# Get view count in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have code like this for count view after visit my page.
But this code add two not one.
`web.php` file:

```
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="test";
$coms_conect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($coms_conect,"utf8");
$coms_conect->query("update news set view=view+1 where id=244");
```

For example befor execute code view is 20 after execute in 22.
This is .htaccess file

```
<IFMODULE mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*) web.php
```

```
php_flag register_globals off
php_value session.auto_start 0 
php_value session.use_only_cookies 1 
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
```

Comment: maybe its my need for more coffee.. but I have no clue what you're asking.. can you clarify?

Comment: Is there more code or that is all?

Comment: No I commit all code.only this code execute.

Comment: Make sure the query is executing only one time in your page. check the included files in that page.

Comment: What is "sub two not one"???

Comment: I'm sorry .I edit my post. add two not one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem. What happens is that the script is getting executed twice. The reason for that is because the browser tries to get a .ico file from the server. And from what i am guessing you have some kind of routing in php. Have a look at access logs of the server and you will know the reason.I am pretty sure that is the problem.

**Edit**

*Not the best solution* This is specific to condition if you want to edit your web.php file. Although there are better alternatives.

```
/* This will only tract /home,/ and /temp url.
   You can edit them on your own
*/
$allowed_hosts = array("/home","/","/temp");
if(in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $allowed_hosts)
{
    //execute sql query here
}
```

*Alternatively better solution*

What i was saying by views is. Where you have written you html tag as in

```
<?php
    ....
    //You can add sql here and it wont run twice
?>
<html>
    ....
</html>
```

Try this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="/favicon.ico")
$coms_conect->query("update new_ads set view=view+1 where id=1");
```

Comment: You can't that will always be there. I am guessing you will have to improve your routing scheme to fix this issue. think of it like this. When you load some file, browser will always make .ico request. So i am guessing you have a master router script , for the sake of discussion assume index.php . Now what you need to do is rather than having counter in router script, have it in the specific view file. That way counter goes up only when actual url resource is fetched.

Comment: Or another method, just get the url being requested in php and check if you want to have counter against that. If yes then execute sql else pass

Comment: Okay so i think you added the code in web.php for the counter. Just read the last comment and check for urls that you want. Although it would be better if you implement that in view. That way you save a if condition which is good if you are profiling the app. (Note : View is where you are generating the html. Because i think that you are not using a framework)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108795/discussion-between-paranoid-and-georoot).

Comment: Hi can you see this post?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551265/load-form-several-time-in-php

Comment: @paranoid sure one minute

Answer (score 0):

Different ways of solving this, depending on what you want

1. if you want this view to be updated once, when someone first enters your website (so not for every page on every reload)
   Create a one time only redirect page, for example when you visit : 
   www.yourURLaddress.com it opens Index.php which only contains this :

   ```
   $host="localhost";
   $user="root";
   $password="";
   $dbname="test";
   $coms_conect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
   mysqli_set_charset($coms_conect,"utf8");
   $coms_conect->query("update news set view=view+1 where id=244");
   $newURL = "home.php";
   header('Location: ' . $newURL);
   ```

   If you have a framework routing your webpage, simply change the last two
   lines to redirect you to your correct URI for example:

   ```
    $newURL = "/URI"; (i.e. /home , /login, /whatever URI you have set)
    header('Location: ' . $newURL);
   ```
2. if you want this view to be updated on every page but only once during this person's visit.
   Use a cookie, in php simply create a cookie after sending your +view to the MySQL database, set it's key to your pagename (with a variable) and set it to 1, so it only gets sent to the DB once:

   ```
   if (!isset($_COOKIE[$pagename]) || $_COOKIE["pagename"] != 1) {

       $host="localhost";
       $user="root";
       $password="";
       $dbname="test";
       $coms_conect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
       mysqli_set_charset($coms_conect,"utf8");
       $coms_conect->query("update news set view=view+1 where id=244");
       $_COOKIE[$pagename] = 1;

   }
   ```
3. If you want this view to be updated for every view on every page on every reload but only once instead of twice on your single page reload:

   Do the same as mentioned above but then whenever you click a link, you
   simply set the cookie to 0 and instead of using a pagename for the key of 
   the cookie, simply use a general name like `$_COOKIE['view_counted'];`