# Load form several time in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have .htaccess file like this:

```
<IFMODULE mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) new_web.php
</IFMODULE>

php_flag register_globals off
php_value session.auto_start 0 
php_value session.use_only_cookies 1 
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
```

When I load this url

```
http://localhost/test_title/en/test
```

this is my apache `access.log`

```
::1 - - [11/Apr/2016:18:41:02 +0430] "GET /test_title/en/test HTTP/1.1" 200 12072 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [11/Apr/2016:18:41:03 +0430] "GET /dynamics/captcha.php HTTP/1.1" 200 992 "http://localhost/test_title/en/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [11/Apr/2016:18:41:03 +0430] "GET /test_title/en/test HTTP/1.1" 200 12072 "http://localhost/test_title/en/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [11/Apr/2016:18:41:03 +0430] "GET /test_title/en/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 16637 "http://localhost/test_title/en/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [11/Apr/2016:18:41:03 +0430] "GET /test_title/en/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 16637 "http://localhost/test_title/fa/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [11/Apr/2016:18:41:03 +0430] "GET /test_title/en/test HTTP/1.1" 200 12072 "http://localhost/test_title/fa/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
```

I want load this url `/test_title/en/test` Once not three times

Comment: use `php -S 0.0.0.0:80 new_web.php` to run server rather that nginx. That way you can debug requests as they come in. Also if in browser you see multiple requests in logs, try using curl and see if you get one request or multiple.

Comment: I have apache server. can you more explain?

Comment: Basically rather that using apache server , use PHP internal server just for debugging. That way you get condole output whenever the application sends a request and you can debug more effectively rather that reading apache logs every time. And then try to load the application and see how many requests are made. Also if there is a Location redirect requests might be more because of that